# source for native sun.misc.Unsafe operations in java

Tags: multithreading, native, atomic, java

i've downloaded "openjdk-6-src-b23-05_jul_2011" to have a look at the native implementations for the methods in sun.misc.Unsafe. e.g. compareAndSwapInt(...) but i am not able find anything in the downloaded sources of openjdk. i want to get an idea how these methods look like (i was interested in the atomic stuff the jdk provides).

could anybody point me to the right location(s)?

```
$ ls jdk/src/
linux  share  solaris  windows

$ ls hotspot/src/os/
linux  posix  solaris  windows
```

any help appreciated

marcel

Comment: You should accept some answers to prevous question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Implementation of unsafe methods itself is not OS-specific, therefore it can be found in `hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp`. It delegates to `hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/atomic.cpp`, which includes OS and CPU specific files, such as `hotspot/src/os_cpu/windows_x86/atomic_windows_x86.inline.hpp`.

Comment: thanks very much. this is what i was looking for. i love stackoverflow and the people here! is there a mapping somewhere between the java method name like "compareAndSwapInt" and the *.cpp version? my 'grep -ri "compareAndSwapInt" *' didn't return anything.

Comment: i think i found it, file http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp line: 1458

Answer (score 0):

Gcc atomic builtins as provided like java

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

But problem is there is no standard, as you move to solaris, you will need something else. So you have to use different system call as you change your platform.